# JXTreeTable selection by code

Tags: java, selection, jxtreetable

I need to ask for a little hint about node selection in my `JXTreeTable`.

I added some nodes to it and want to select one node as Default by program. My test function for selecting a node looks like this:

```
public void setSelectionTest()
{        
    Object                      dfltObj;
    TreeSelectionModel          tsm             =   jttRulesSet.getTreeSelectionModel();
    TreeTableModelRules         ttm             =   (TreeTableModelRules)jttRulesSet.getTreeTableModel();
    TreePath                    tp;

    dfltObj                                     =   ttm.getChild(ttm.getRoot(), 0);
    if( (dfltObj != null) )
    {
        System.out.println("Node to select: " + dfltObj.getClass());
        tp                                      =   new TreePath(dfltObj);
        tsm.setSelectionPath(tp);
        jttRulesSet.scrollPathToVisible(tp);
    }
```

My test function for verifiing the effect:

```
public void getSelectionTest()
{
     TreeSelectionModel             tsm;
     TreePath                       treeSelPath;

     Object                         dfltNode;

     tsm                                        =   jttRulesSet.getTreeSelectionModel();            // get treeselectionmodel
     treeSelPath                                =   tsm.getSelectionPath();                         // get selected path 
     if(treeSelPath != null)
     {
         dfltNode                               =   treeSelPath.getLastPathComponent();
         System.out.println("Selected node: " + ((RulesSet) dfltNode).getName());                   // info bout the selected path
         System.out.println("Selected node: " + tsm.getSelectionCount());
     }
}
```

I get Name and number of selected row. So far OK. But the `JXTreeTable` shows no selection. The `jttRulesSet.expandPath(tp)` line has no effect as well. There must be an undiscovered fact behind...

Can somebody give me any tip to solve this problem?